# smallest independent set

Tags: constraints, z3, satisfiability

Given a set `s` of formula,  I want to find a smallest subset `s'` of `s` that implies every formula in `s`.  I call `s` the smallest independent set because for every pair `a,b` in `s'` , `a` does not imply `b` and vice versa.

It seems to me the naive approach would take `O(2^|s|)` complexity.  Is there a more efficient method ?  Can this problem be encoded some how that can take advantage of current smt/sat solvers (e.g. unsat core)?

Comment: I think you can use Z3 for that. That looks like a use-case for [Arrays and Bags](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h26). However, Z3 will not give you any information on runtime-complexity. Also, since the problem is sat, it can only ever solve the problem for a given instance (and not the general case). Personally, would find it easier to write down your problem in [Alloy](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/) than Z3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late for you now. But you can compute such a set by 1 loop.

```
IS = F1 // first formula in s
for each formula Fi in {F2,..Fn} in s
  if ((not IS) AND Fi) is UNSAT
     IS = IS AND Fi
```

The set `IS` contains the independent set.

Comment: this computes an independent set, but not necessarily the smallest one.